# Get Oh-My-ZSH history behaviour in Prezto

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, prezto

In Oh My Zsh, by default, the history feature matches prefixes.

Typing `ls` and hitting Up Arrow will scroll through commands that **start with** what you typed: matching `ls` and `ls -l` but **not** `echo ls`.

In Prezto, by default, the history feature matches anywhere in the string.

Typing `ls` and hitting Up Arrow will scroll through commands that **contain** what you typed: matching `ls` and `ls -l` and **also** `echo ls`.

Is there a way to set Prezto to match prefixes only, like the Oh My Zsh default behaviour?

(According to the `history-substring-search` documentation, setting `HISTORY_SUBSTRING_SEARCH_PREFIXED=1` will do this, but I have this set in `.zshrc` and it still matches anywhere in the string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found that instead of using whatever plugin comes with Prezto, it is possible to use built-in zsh features instead.

Add the following to the end of `~/.zshrc` :

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search
```